# Why were kandarian demons able to operate during daylight in the Middle Ages?

Tags: army-of-darkness

In *Evil Dead 2: Dead By Dawn*, Ash is freed from possession by a kandarian demon by the light of dawn.  It is also shown that the demons come out at night.

This idea is consistent with most of what we see in *Evil Dead: Army of Darkness*, as Ash has to seek shelter in the windmill as night falls, and the army of the dead attacks at night.

Yet at the end of *Evil Dead 2* (and at the beginning of *Army of Darkness*), after Ash is sucked through the vortex, he finds himself surrounded by medieval soldiers, and shoots an attacking kandarian demon out of the air *in broad daylight*.

Later on in *Army of Darkness*, Ash is thrown into the Pit, where he fights multiple kandarian demons during the day (and one of them climbs out of the Pit into the sunlight).

What protection does sunlight offer?  Why did dawn free Ash from possession, and keep the Evil Dead at bay, but still allow some kandarian demons to act apparently freely?

Comment: They may have been middle, but these ages were also dark! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that being out in the daytime only weakens demons who are in their true form - if so, the demons seen during the day in AoD are likely in their own physical bodies, not possessing an unwilling host.

It's also possible that in Evil Dead 2 the demons were just screwing with Ash - trying to give him false hope and get more fun out of playing with him.  They hadn't had much to do for a while and didn't really think he was a threat at the time.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that the Kandarian Demons are only vulnerable to sunlight in the early stages of their resurrection, but develop an immunity to it as they consume increasing numbers of victims.

Comment: Hmmm. Is there any explicit confirmation of this?

Comment: @Adamant: Nope.  This is pure conjecture.

Answer (score -2):

Or it could just be related to the widely believed mystical significance of dawn, purification, renewable, all that jazz.