# Why was Ash able to overcome the possessing spirits?

Tags: evil-dead-2

In *Evil Dead 2*, Ash is possesed. I would like to know: why was he was able to overcome the evil spirits and save his soul? Is he more virtuous than others, or is there another reason?

Answer (score 2):

There are two scenes where Ash "overcomes" the possessing Kandarian demon.

The first scene is merely, as [DoctorWho22](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54631/1359) mentions, lucky timing: the sun rises while Ash is still outside, and the sunshine ([for some unexplained reason](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9629/1359) drives the possessing demon out.

The second scene, however, occurs when Ash is once again possessed, inside the cabin, and is attacking the remaining survivors.  When Annie is apparently helpless, Ash happens to notice the necklace he had given to his (now deceased) girlfriend, Linda, lying on the floor:

[image]

Ash hesitates, reaches for the necklace, then breaks free from the Kandarian influence.  While not explicitly stated, presumably this is because the sight of the necklace reminds Ash of the love he had for Linda, and the sorrow of her loss.  The best explanation I have is that the strength of the emotion (or perhaps the sappier "love conquers all" motif) forces the invading presence out of him, allowing him to re-assert control.

Venturing into the realm of more speculative theory, it is also possible that his repeated exposure to possession attempts has given him a bit more "resistance" than normal.  Because the sun drove the first invading spirit out, perhaps that explains why only his hand was possessed the second time, instead of his entire body.  If there is a relationship between those events, then it might also be a possible explanation for throwing off the third possession (with a little help from the memory trigger from the necklace).

Answer (score 1):

So you're talking about the 2nd Evil Dead film where he is no longer possessed when dawn comes right?

He becomes a Deadite and then is released by the coming of dawn.

http://evildead.wikia.com/wiki/Ashley_J_Williams

> While she is changing Ash finds the book and the tape recorder he
>   plays it until "The Evil" breaks though the window and steals Linda
>   away and the evil spirit attacks Ash. afterwards the movie picks up
>   again and continues where the original left off with Ash being carried
>   a good distance by the demon, Ash is slammed hard against a tree and
>   falls in a puddle of water. From here he becomes a deadite but shortly
>   afterwards is released from the spirit by the coming of dawn, only to
>   pass out. Ash regains consciousness moments before sunset.